# Resharper issue with Blazor

Tags: visual-studio, razor, resharper

I am using Resharper Ultimate 2020.1 with Visual Studio 2019 Professional and the Intellisense in Blazor component stopped to work. When I suspend Resharper everything comes back to work.

[image]

Is there someone who found a solution?
Thanks.